# PHP continue curl login script in browser

Tags: php, session, curl, authentication, continue

I have a curl PHP login script for a 3rd party website, which works like a charm!

```
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 
$url="https://example.com"; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 


$postdata = "subUserId=&loginId=".$username."&password=".$password."&go=&__FORM_ID=";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;
```

If I run this script, $result contains the member area of this site. The problem is, that I want to continue the session of my PHP script inside my browser. I can't click on an element, because the host of the website is getting replaced with my host. e.g. "https://example.com/email" is now "http://localhost:8080/email". If I open the webpage manually I'm not logged in, because the session is stored for my local php script and not for the destination website.

Is there a way to pass the session to my browser? Maybe it's possible to "let the browser think" that it's on "https://example.com", instead of "http://localhost:8080", so that the session variables get saved to the right URL.

I only want to use this script to login, not to do any actions on the target website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to hijack a session, that is not possible that way. The only thing you can do is make your server act as a proxy to that remote site. That means you need to filter all content through a filter to replace all references and you need to take care of all cookies involved.

Comment: Does `$result` contain a resource token? Or some sort of token you can use as bearer to continue the 'session'? Most oAuth endpoints, on authentication, will respond with a bearer, an encoded instruction allowing you to 'act' as the user who has logged in to that service. Perhaps export this variable and provide us with documentation to this gateway (you could locally store it in a session or a database for continuous use even when the user is not 'active')

Comment: Oh, I see, you're trying to scrape the page? See @arkascha comment, you are looking to create a proxy to the site rather than a control point

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue, with a workaround.

I just created a html form, with the 3rd party url as target. My login credentials are getting passed as hidden variables. Then I added a short Javascript code, that clicks on "submit", as soon as the page is loaded.
Edit: Do not use this on a public website, because your login credentials are stored visible inside the source code.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('submit').click();
};
</script>


<form action="https://example.com/login"  method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="subUserId" name="subUserId" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="loginId" name="loginId" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
  <input type="hidden" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>">
  <input type="hidden" id="go" name="go" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="__FORM_ID" name="__FORM_ID" value="">

  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: That means everyone can sniff out your credentials.

Comment: Yes, if this would be a public domain you were right. But this script is just hosted on my local php server, where no one has access to.

Comment: Then why the effort at all? Why can't you simply store the credentials in your browser?

Comment: To keep things short, my 3 advantages of this are:
1. I needed a browser independent solution.
2. I can easily change the creditials on my SQL server, without updating the password on every used browser.
3. I could host this script on a local connected server, so that every employee in the LAN can use this (They know the credentials anyway).